# reference request: hormander paper

Tags: reference-request, spectral-theory, means, eigenfunctions, elliptic-equations

Did someone know where to find the paper: On the Riesz means of spectral functions and eigenfunction expansions for elliptic differential operators of Lars Hormander?

Comment: L. Hörmander, *On the Riesz means of spectral functions and eigenfunction expansions for elliptic differential operators*. In *Some recent advances in the basic sciences*, Yeshiva University, New York (1966), 155–202. or [this 1968 translated version](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=mat&paperid=481&option_lang=eng) in Matematika if you read Russian.

Comment: Thank you, do you know where I can find a not russian version? I am not able to find it

Comment: There are no online version.  Try your university library.